# How can I catch a marshalling error in Go?

Tags: go

I have an API that is expecting a "username":"string" request body, I am unmarshalling the request body into a user struct that matches what I am expecting. My code does not throw an error on mismatched struct data. Is there a function I could use instead of json.Unmarshal? If not how would I be able to catch a 400 error in this case?  (I have also tried using json.decoder)

Here is my code:

```
type User struct {
   Username string `json:"username" gorm:"primary_key;Column:username"`
}

var user models.User

body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
if err = json.Unmarshal(body, &user); err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`DisallowUnknownFields`](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Decoder.DisallowUnknownFields) option of [`json.Decoder`](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Decoder) to cause an error when the decoder finds a field that is not in the struct:

> DisallowUnknownFields causes the Decoder to return an error when the destination is a struct and the input contains object keys which do not match any non-ignored, exported fields in the destination.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to both ensure that the key `"username"` is present, and that other fields are not, you would need to implement the [`Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interface, and iterate over all of the received keys.

```
func (user *User) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) (error) {                                                    
    d := make(map[string]interface{})                                                                                                    
    err = json.Unmarshal(data, &d)                                                                         
    if err != nil {                                                                                               
        return err
    }
    if _, ok := d["username"]; !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("username is required")
    }
    for k, v := range d {
        if k == "username" {
            username, ok := v.(string)
            if !ok {
                return fmt.Errorf("username must be a string, got %T", v)
            }
            user.Username = username
        } else {
            return fmt.Errorf("Unexpected key %s", k)
        }
    }
    return                                                                                                  
}
```